# TinyMCE: Programmatically select word at caret position

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How can I modify the current selection from `tinyMCE 4`  so that it can be extended to the current word's boundary?

Say the caret is at the position represented below. How can I force `tinyMCE` to select the `'test'` word?

> This is a t|est

I suspect that may to use the browser's Range object, but I'm not sure how to do this

My end goal is that when I trigger a custom action from a button, it applies to either the selection (if there is one), or to the word containing the caret position. Basically, same behavior at when you click the Bold button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you already have the fundamentals of how to add a button to the TinyMCE and how to call a function and all that. So I'm only going to answer the 'how to mark the work at caret position?' part.

If the editable content is a textarea, use this:

```js
;(function() {
  var position
  
  var elem = document.getElementById('ex')
  elem.addEventListener('click', renderClick)
  
  function renderClick(evt) {
    let textUntilCaret = this.textContent.substr(0, this.selectionStart)
    textUntilCaret = textUntilCaret.replace(/\w+$/, '')
    
    let textFromCaret = this.textContent.substr(this.selectionStart)
    textFromCaret = textFromCaret.replace(/^\w+/, '')
    
    this.selectionStart = textUntilCaret.length
    this.selectionEnd = this.textContent.length - textFromCaret.length
  }
  
  function startWordAtPosition() {
    
  }
  
})();
```

```html
Click in the textarea and the whole word will be selected!<br>
<textarea name="" id="ex" cols="50" rows="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, officiis et reiciendis maxime ipsam doloribus quo inventore animi voluptatibus maiores eligendi, corrupti cum placeat nobis possimus exercitationem ratione aut. Explicabo deserunt eum natus id laudantium repellendus aliquam magni molestias et, nihil asperiores obcaecati dolores sapiente. Nisi fugiat, beatae possimus impedit dolore quos nihil illo mollitia at exercitationem quo dignissimos eum, dolorum, delectus vel error sunt placeat eos ut. Suscipit, architecto perferendis. Minus debitis optio ratione aperiam sapiente est blanditiis vero cum alias accusantium veniam, molestiae odit soluta esse sint dolore dignissimos culpa autem ullam molestias repudiandae ab vitae eligendi inventore! Inventore, quas perspiciatis cumque repellat distinctio odio facilis explicabo ab molestiae laboriosam illo est at excepturi, deleniti dolore eum impedit quam voluptates. Totam quasi veniam dolor omnis magni atque, ex minus officia at adipisci similique a soluta possimus vitae blanditiis minima. Odit sequi blanditiis nesciunt, nemo reprehenderit dignissimos voluptatum aut, ex saepe ipsa itaque nobis similique, expedita eum sapiente quibusdam inventore aliquam et. Enim consequuntur, ipsam possimus quia perferendis obcaecati similique laborum! Tempora minus, repellat repellendus itaque obcaecati optio autem ad velit blanditiis id quasi quia quaerat fuga at praesentium hic accusamus assumenda. Doloribus sit distinctio vitae nostrum quo maiores, aperiam eius exercitationem suscipit quod et explicabo. Alias, explicabo quidem? Ipsum, fugiat aliquam obcaecati ab tempore ducimus pariatur, itaque, consequuntur ea beatae consectetur. Modi ducimus perspiciatis asperiores atque neque iste, eligendi odio voluptatibus labore, dolorem, iusto ipsa hic rem facere. Tempora officia doloribus repellendus excepturi, eaque temporibus architecto non sequi cupiditate harum pariatur, alias quia beatae voluptatem quas, vel illo inventore eligendi deserunt cumque laudantium id nulla. Eos cum soluta magnam quam, aliquam facere accusantium quasi, minus doloremque adipisci incidunt debitis non tempore! Perspiciatis eius illum maiores nam laborum dicta repellendus similique incidunt, cum ut, aliquid eveniet? Voluptatum, doloremque et?</textarea>
```

If the editable content is a div with attribute `contenteditable` set, use this:
It even works with child elements and mixed text nodes and child element:
This does not work in MSIE11 and below,

```js
console.clear();
;(function() {
  var position

  var elem = document.getElementById('ex')
  elem.addEventListener('click', renderClick)

  function renderClick(evt) {
    let caretPosition = getCaretPosition(evt.target);
    let caretNode = getCaretTextNode(evt);

    let textUntilCaret = caretNode.textContent.substr(0, caretPosition)
    textUntilCaret = textUntilCaret.replace(/\w+$/, '')

    let textFromCaret = caretNode.textContent.substr(caretPosition)
    textFromCaret = textFromCaret.replace(/^\w+/, '')

    selectRange(caretNode, textUntilCaret.length, caretNode.textContent.length - textFromCaret.length)
  }

  function selectRange(node, start, end) {
    // console.log(node, start, end)
    let range = document.createRange()
    range.selectNodeContents(node)
    range.setStart(node, start)
    range.setEnd(node, end)

    selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);    
  }

  function getCaretTextNode(evt) {
    var range, textNode
    // standard
    if (document.caretPositionFromPoint) {
      range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
      textNode = range.offsetNode;
      // WebKit
    } else if (document.caretRangeFromPoint) {
      range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
      textNode = range.startContainer;
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
      // range = document.body.createTextRange();
      // range.moveToPoint(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
      // range.select();
      var sel = document.getSelection()
      textNode = sel.focusNode
    }
    return textNode;
  }

  function getCaretPosition(editableDiv) {
    var caretPos = 0,
        sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if (range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode == editableDiv) {
          caretPos = range.endOffset;
        }
      }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
      range = document.selection.createRange();
      if (range.parentElement() == editableDiv) {
        var tempEl = document.createElement("span");
        editableDiv.insertBefore(tempEl, editableDiv.firstChild);
        var tempRange = range.duplicate();
        tempRange.moveToElementText(tempEl);
        tempRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", range);
        caretPos = tempRange.text.length;
      }
    }
    return caretPos;
  }  


})();
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="ex">Lorem   ipsum dolor <b>sit amet</b> consectetur <em>adipisicing</em> elit. Itaque, officiis et reiciendis maxime ipsam doloribus quo inventore animi voluptatibus maiores eligendi, corrupti cum placeat nobis possimus exercitationem ratione aut. Explicabo deserunt eum natus id laudantium repellendus <span>aliquam magni molestias et, nihil asperiores obcaecati dolores </span>sapiente. Nisi fugiat, beatae possimus impedit dolore quos nihil illo mollitia at exercitationem quo dignissimos eum, dolorum, delectus vel error sunt placeat eos ut.   Suscipit, <span>architecto perferendis</span>. Minus debitis optio ratione aperiam sapiente est blanditiis vero cum alias accusantium veniam, molestiae odit soluta esse sint dolore dignissimos culpa autem ullam molestias   repudiandae ab vitae eligendi inventore! Inventore, quas perspiciatis cumque repellat distinctio odio facilis explicabo ab molestiae laboriosam illo est at excepturi, deleniti dolore eum impedit quam voluptates. Totam quasi veniam   dolor omnis magni atque, ex minus officia at adipisci similique a soluta possimus vitae blanditiis minima. Odit sequi blanditiis nesciunt, nemo reprehenderit dignissimos voluptatum aut, ex saepe ipsa itaque nobis similique, expedita eum sapiente quibusdam inventore aliquam et. Enim consequuntur, ipsam possimus quia perferendis obcaecati similique laborum! Tempora minus, repellat repellendus itaque obcaecati optio autem ad velit blanditiis id quasi quia quaerat fuga at praesentium hic accusamus assumenda. Doloribus sit distinctio vitae nostrum quo maiores, aperiam eius exercitationem suscipit quod et explicabo. Alias, explicabo quidem? Ipsum, fugiat aliquam obcaecati ab tempore ducimus pariatur, itaque, consequuntur ea beatae consectetur. Modi ducimus perspiciatis asperiores atque neque iste, eligendi odio voluptatibus labore, dolorem, iusto ipsa hic rem facere. Tempora officia doloribus repellendus excepturi, eaque temporibus architecto non sequi cupiditate harum pariatur, alias quia beatae voluptatem quas, vel illo inventore eligendi deserunt cumque laudantium id nulla. Eos cum soluta magnam quam, aliquam facere accusantium quasi, minus doloremque adipisci incidunt debitis non tempore! Perspiciatis eius illum maiores nam laborum dicta repellendus similique incidunt, cum ut, aliquid eveniet? Voluptatum, doloremque et?</div>
```